# Install Pylucene on Windows, "Make" command does not work

Tags: python, lucene, installation, pylucene

I was trying to setup the Pylucene on Windows10, the first few steps are successful, but after I make edits in my MAKEFILE:

```
PREFIX_PYTHON=C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
ANT=C:/apache-ant-1.9.14/bin/ant
JAVA_HOME=C:/Progra~1/Java/jdk1.8.0_241
PYTHON=$(PREFIX_PYTHON)/python.exe
#JCC=$(PYTHON) -m jcc --shared --find-jvm-dll
JCC=$(PYTHON) -m jcc
NUM_FILES=10
```

And then I execute command(Anaconda) ‘make’ under directory ‘PyLucene-8.1.1’ to build the whole project, it always shows:

(base) C:\pylucene-8.1.1>make
'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

I really have no clue on this, can anyone help me out? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this error, follow this - https://superuser.com/a/808818

Also, you can directly download 'make for windows' from here - https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/postdownload